# React Spotify App Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, spotify-app

I'm creating a Spotify App using Spotify API along with ReactJS. I've been following this [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-spotify-player-with-react-in-15-minutes-7e01991bc4b6)

The Spotify app works as it is suppose to, that is until I get to the Spotify Authorization page I receive an error message "Cannot read property 'item' of undefined:

> Cannot read property 'item' of undefined
>       at Object.success (App.js:40)

which is this line of code:

```
success: (data) => {
                console.log("data", data);
                this.setState({
                    item: data.item,
                    is_playing: data.is_playing,
                    progress_ms: data.progress_ms,
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Full App.js code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import * as $ from 'jquery';
    import { AUTH_ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID_KEY, REDIRECT_URI, SCOPE } from './config';
    import hash from "./hash";
    import Player from "./Player";
    import logo from "./logo.svg";
    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                token: null,
                item: {
                    album: {
                        images: [{ url: "" }]
                    },
                    name: "",
                    artists: [{ name: "" }],
                    duration_ms:0,
                },
                is_playing: "Paused",
                progress_ms: 0
            };

            this.getCurrentlyPlaying = this.getCurrentlyPlaying.bind(this);
        }

        getCurrentlyPlaying(token) {
            // Make a call using the token
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player",
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: (xhr) => {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                },
                success: (data) => {
                    console.log("data", data);
                    this.setState({
                        item: data.item,
                        is_playing: data.is_playing,
                        progress_ms: data.progress_ms,
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            // Set token
            let _token = hash.access_token;

            if (_token) {
                // Set token
                this.setState({
                    token: _token
                });
                this.getCurrentlyPlaying(_token);
            }
        }

        render() {

            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <header className="App-header">
                        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                        {!this.state.token && (
                            <a className="btn btn--loginApp-link" href={`${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`}>
                                Login to Spotify </a>
                        )}
                        {this.state.token && (
                            <Player
                                item={this.state.item}
                                is_playing={this.state.is_playing}
                                progress_ms={this.progress_ms}
                            />
                        )}
                    </header>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


    //  Will redirect the user to the /authorize endpoint of the Accounts service
    const authEndpoint = AUTH_ENDPOINT;

    // App client ID, redirect URI and scopes
    const clientId = CLIENT_ID_KEY;
    const redirectURI = REDIRECT_URI;
    const scopes = SCOPE;



    export default App;
```

Comment: What does `console.log("data", data);` log ?

Comment: do a check beforehand? `success: data => { if(data) { this.setState({ ... }); } else { console.error();} }` ?

Comment: @klugjo console.log returns 'data undefined'

Comment: @JeeMok That worked. Also, I foolishly didn't realize I had to login and actually play   a song so that the app received data. Thanks